# Problems allocating memory with Contiguous Memory Allocator (CMA) Linux device driver development

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to test Contiguous Memory Allocator for DMA mapping framework. I have compiled kernel 3.5.7 with CMA support, I know that it is experimental but it should work. 
My goal is to allocate several 32MB physically contiguous memory chunks in kernel module for device without scatter/gather capability.

I am testing my system with test patch from Barry Song: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1263136

But when I try to allocate memory with `echo 1024 > /dev/cma_test`. I get `bash: echo: write error: No space left on device`. And in dmesg:`misc cma_test: no mem in CMA area`

What could be the problem? What am I missing? System is freshly rebooted and there should be at least 350mb of free contiguous memory because bigphysarea patch on kernel 3.2 were able to allocate that amount on similar system.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: try to use boot-time memory allocation...

Comment: I would prefer (well it is one of requirements) for this to be in kernel module and I don't think boot-time memory allocation supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have decided to use kernel 3.5 and bigphysarea patch(from 3.2). It is easy and works like a charm.

CMA is great option as well but it is a bit harder to use an debug(CMA needs actual device). I have used up all my skills to find what was the problem. Printk inside kernel code was only possibility to debug this one.